# saving javascript/angularjs null as python none using google app engine as datastore

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, angularjs

I have a form which I save by calling a webservice using $http.get in angularjs.
 If one of the input fields does not contain anything, the value is saved as null. And when I reload the page, the input field contains "null" replacing my placeholder-text. An example of one of my input fields is:

```
<input placeholder="Notes" type="text" ng-model="notes">
```

How do I save a null-value in a form, that does not overwrite the placeholder-text ?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be handled in the read (server side) handler(get request to read).